# Select title 2 if title 1 does not exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT i.title, j.title FROM table1 i JOIN table2 j ON i.id = j.table1_id
```

Now what I would like is to select `i.title AS title` if `i.title` exists, otherwise use `j.title AS title`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.title, j.title) title 
FROM   items i 
       LEFT JOIN table j 
           ON i.id = j.items_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `IFNULL()` in MySQL:

```
SELECT IFNULL(i.title, j.title)
FROM table1 i 
JOIN table2 j ON i.id = j.table1_id
```

It  will return `j.title` if `i.title` is null.